# GoogleScript > Installable Trigger > onOpen() not called if SpreadSheet is opened from Android Device, why?

Tags: android, google-apps-script, triggers, spreadsheet

Every time I open my spreadsheet I want a function `updatePrices()` to be invoked. This function does get some data via an api-url and then it updates the spreadsheet with the collected information.

For that I created an installable Trigger with the following settings:

- Function to run = updatePrices()
- Event source = From spreadsheet
- Event type = On open

When I open the Spreadsheet from a Browser on my Computer, it just works perfectly.
When I open the Spreadsheet from my Android Device, it just does not update the prices at all.

Do you have any ideas why?
Any workarounds or fixes?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a [simple `onOpen()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger instead of an installable one.

Also, you can file an issue on Google issue tracker at the [android component](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190923%20status:open) or go into this issue [onOpen event in Android mobile app does not fire triggers](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765325) which it is very similar if not the same as yours.